# How to create directory structure for gradle subProjects?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, directory, structure, project

I have a root project with three subprojects

```
root
|
|-subA
|-subB
|-subB
```

the build.gradle file in root has this content

```
allprojects {
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.zeromq:jeromq:0.3.+'
        compile files('../lib/tibrvj.jar')
    }
    eclipse {
        classpath {
            downloadJavadoc=true
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
        test.java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        test.resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '2.2'
}

task srcDirs << { 
    subprojects.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{f -> println(f)}
    subprojects.sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs.each{f -> println(f)}
    subprojects.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs.each{f -> println(f)}
    subprojects.sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs.each{f -> println(f)}
}
```

I do not know how I can create all the directories with this config. The other gradle.build files are empty at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're trying to change from the defaults, you shouldn't need to set the sourceSets directories in the subprojects.

Have you tried something like:

```
subprojects { 
  task makeSrcDirs << {
     sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs*.mkdirs()
     sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs*.mkdirs()
     sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs*.mkdirs()
     sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs*.mkdirs()
  }
}
```

Comment: this works. Why doesn't gradle create these directories on its own?

Comment: Gradle can (in a limited fashion): http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html

Comment: Could not find method leftShift() for arguments ... of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.